# Android - AdMob is not loading Ads by giving Error code 0

Tags: android, firebase, admob

I've used Firebase to impelment AdMob in some of my apps,In all apps it is working fine but in 1 of the apps it is giving following error:

> There was a problem getting an ad response. ErrorCode: 0 Ads: Failed
>   to load ad: 0

I have tried many solutions from google but not gain yet, Unit-Ids are OK as well. Ads are loading in test devices but live Ads are causing the issue. I have tried by changing the package name and creating new App at AdMob but still same issue. Code piece is as following. What is the issue?

```
MobileAds.initialize(this, "ca-app-pub-8845338895058113~6722149984");
            adInterstial = new AdInterstial(SplashActivity.this);
            mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
            final AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
                    .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)
                     .addTestDevice(getString(R.string.admob_test_device))
                    .build();
            mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

xml code

```
<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id"
        android:visibility="visible"
        />
```

Comment: if you admob email is new, wait 1/2 days

Comment: It is not new, I have linked my some other apps in past and they are OK.

Comment: Have you added AdActivity in your manifest file ??? If not then add it, next if still it doesn't work properly, then change your AdRequest with this line because i've faced the same issue....
AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();

In layout:-
set width of your adView to match_parent

Answer (score 0):

Its take some more time to come your ads in live.so wait for a few hours and try again.

From google [Mobile Ads SDK Team](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!category-topic/google-admob-ads-sdk/android/fBe3YL3ffpo) answer  it could be that you have only recently created a new Ad Unit ID and requesting for live ads. It could take a few hours for ads to start getting served if that is that case. If you are receiving test ads then your implementation is fine. Just wait a few hours and see if you are able to receive live ads then. If not, can send us your Ad Unit ID for us to look into.

**Note :** Google updated (Firebase and the Mobile Ads SDK) for mobile ads.Check you done all process from [Google Mobile Ads SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admob/android/quick-start)

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:9.8.0
```

Comment: It have tried and waited many time in past few days but no gain yet. I even created new application and used new Unit Ids still the issue is same. Can't figure out the exact reason.

Comment: you try  with test ads if its worked means no problem in your code..you have to wait few more hours..

Comment: Ads: Received error HTTP response code: 403
sometimes Log displays this as well.

Comment: your playservice version??

Comment: playservice version is: 9877000 and yes all is setup just like my other apps which are working fine.

Comment: did you check with emulator or device?

Comment: Test Ads are working in both. With Test Ads I mean the Ads are requested with live Unit Ids but I have added Test Devices. and I have checked playservices version in xml.

Answer (score 0):

Error code 0 can be thrown because of many reasons, but mostly it will be (from my personal experience) because of the following two reasons:

1. You have just created your ad unit so it's not initialised by google till now. So wait for at least 3 to 4 hours.
2. You have not initialised admob in your android app .

   ```
   MobileAds.initialize(this, "YOUR_APP_ID");
   ```

so make sure to do that .